# Do I need to delete the pointer in the loop here?

Tags: c++, pointers

If I have something like this:

```
for(MyClass* m : a_container){
    //
    //Do something with m
    //
    //delete m;    ?
}

//delete m;    ?
```

Do I need to delete `m` within each loop iteration, or just at the end because the same pointer is being re-used?

NB: I know I should use `shared_ptr`s but this is for a specific reason.

Comment: Regarding `shared_ptr`s, I think far too many people automatically go with a `shared_ptr` even though shared semantics are unnecessary.  A `shared_ptr` does have more overhead than a `unique_ptr`, for example, because of synchronization, etc.  Make sure you actually need shared semantics before using a `shared_ptr`.  If not, go with a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: This question is ridiculous - there is no way to answer it (-1)

Comment: @DieterLücking the person below managed to answer it fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not whether `m` should be deleted, but whether what it *points* to should be. If you are iterating over a container whose elements are pointers and require deletion at that point in time, you may do `delete m;`. `m` itself doesn't need to be deleted as its being created on the stack, there's no use of `new` in creating the actual pointer, so there is no need to call `delete`.

Comment: Yes I didn't want to delete the actual elements from the container, I thought that I was creating a dangling pointer each time- but you say these pointers are on the stack I don't need to do anything?

Comment: (Because a new object is not being created, just a pointer (on the stack) to an existing object)

Comment: @user997112 When all iterations are completed `m` will be destroyed from the stack. There's no dangling pointer at all. That would be if the element that it was pointing to went out of scope, and it was pointing to a vacant address.

Comment: Vague as vague can be (-1)

Comment: Then how about you provide some (un)vagueness and enlighten us?

Comment: @DieterLücking Not sure what you mean. Could you explain?

Comment: There is only `for(MyClass* m : a_container)` nothing whatsoever - how you can answer to that???

Comment: @DieterLücking I wasn't looking for code to be the primary source of the question. There's also the words that surround the code block which ask a pretty clear question: The OP is expressing confusion about pointers, dangling pointers, and memory allocation, and he is inquiring about the deletion of `m`. I am trying to clear up that confusion by addressing the misconceptions he may have about that situation. I concede that this post isn't very high-quality, but I still try to help where I can. Besides, it's not as bad as other questions we have seen! :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 You may have added confusion, instead

Comment: @DieterLücking What confusion? Maybe if you point them out, I can revise my question

Comment: @0x499602D2 Question: In what context is the loop running?

Comment: @DieterLücking This is hypothetical code. There is no context.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Then your answer is a hypothetical - hence no answer

Comment: @DieterLücking You don't like hypothetical answers?

Comment: @DieterLücking How do hypothetical answers lead to confusion?